# File system scheme '[local]' not implemented (file: './logs')

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I got this issue when training a BERT model using HuggingFace library on Colab with TPU runtime . I've setup the TPU correctly and check if it is working well .

The Training parameters for BERT model are as follows:

```
from transformers import TFTrainer, TFTrainingArguments

training_args = TFTrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          # output directory
    num_train_epochs=5,              # total number of training epochs
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,  # batch size per device during training
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,   # batch size for evaluation
    warmup_steps=500,                # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
    weight_decay=0.01,               # strength of weight decay
    logging_dir='./logs',            # directory for storing logs
    logging_steps=10,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch"
)
```

The training of model itself is below :

```
with training_args.strategy.scope():
    model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels=2)

trainer = TFTrainer(
    model=model,                         # the instantiated  Transformers model to be trained
    args=training_args,                  # training arguments, defined above
    train_dataset=train_dataset,         # training dataset
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,           # evaluation dataset
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics             
)

trainer.train()
```

However as soon as I execute above trainer it throws this error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:TPU system grpc://10.78.251.74:8470 has already been initialized. Reinitializing the TPU can cause previously created variables on TPU to be lost.
WARNING:tensorflow:TPU system grpc://10.78.251.74:8470 has already been initialized. Reinitializing the TPU can cause previously created variables on TPU to be lost.
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: grpc://10.78.251.74:8470
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: grpc://10.78.251.74:8470
INFO:tensorflow:Clearing out eager caches
INFO:tensorflow:Clearing out eager caches
INFO:tensorflow:Finished initializing TPU system.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished initializing TPU system.
INFO:tensorflow:Found TPU system:
INFO:tensorflow:Found TPU system:
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Workers: 1
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Workers: 1
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores Per Worker: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores Per Worker: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:3, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:3, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:4, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:4, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:5, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:5, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:6, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:6, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0, TPU_SYSTEM, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0, TPU_SYSTEM, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 0, 0)
Some weights of the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased were not used when initializing BertForSequenceClassification: ['cls.seq_relationship.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias', 'cls.predictions.bias', 'cls.predictions.decoder.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias']
- This IS expected if you are initializing BertForSequenceClassification from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing BertForSequenceClassification from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
Some weights of BertForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased and are newly initialized: ['classifier.weight', 'classifier.bias']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-8e05c1767b42> in <module>()
     10 )
     11 
---> 12 trainer.train()

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

UnimplementedError: File system scheme '[local]' not implemented (file: './logs')
    Encountered when executing an operation using EagerExecutor. This error cancels all future operations and poisons their output tensors.
```

Comment: I have also implemented a separate project with the same scripting for training BERT as above but with GPU Colab runtime and it got executed successfully .

Answer (score 1):

Cloud TPUs (specifically using TensorFlow) currently cannot access local directories which is why you see this error.

The quickest/easiest option is to change `./logs` and `./results` to GCS buckets.